# Virtual network interface in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, dns, ip

I know that you can make a virtual network interface in Windows (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236869)), and in Linux it is also pretty easy with ip-aliases, but does something similar exist for **Mac OS X**? I've been looking for loopback adapters, virtual interfaces and couldn't find a good solution.

You can create a new interface in the networking panel, based on an existing interface, but it will not act as a real fully functional interface (if the original interface is inactive, then the derived one is also inactive).

This scenario is needed when working in a completely disconnected situation. Even then, it makes sense to have networking capabilities when running servers in a VMWare installation. Those virtual machines can be reached by their IP address, but not by their DNS name, even if I run a DNS server in one of those virtual machines. By configuring an interface to use the virtual DNS server, I thought I could test some DNS scenario's. Unfortunately, no interface is resolving DNS names if none of them are inactive...

Comment: on your same topic, more or less http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2009/03/virtual-networking-with-virtualbox-on.html

Answer (score 67):

The loopback adapter is always up.

**ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.123.1** will add an alias IP 172.16.123.1 to the loopback adapter

**ifconfig lo0 -alias 172.16.123.1** will remove it

Comment: This is correct for creating an alias, but to my knowledge you cannot define a DNS Server linked to the loopback adapter, so it will not work in my scenario as described above.

Comment: for me this is the best solution. so I can ping from host to vm and vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps my comment is long overdue, but note that an alias can be created on _any_ interface.

Answer (score 31):

Replying in particular to:

> You can create a new interface in the networking panel, based on an existing interface, but it will not act as a real fully functional interface (if the original interface is inactive, then the derived one is also inactive).

This can be achieved using a Tun/Tap device as suggested by psv141, and manipulating the `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` file to add a NetworkService based on either a tun or tap interface. Mac OS X will not allow the creation of a NetworkService based on a virtual network interface, but one can directly manipulate the `preferences.plist` file to add the NetworkService by hand. Basically you would open the `preferences.plist` file in Xcode (or edit the XML directly, but Xcode is likely to be more fool-proof), and copy the configuration from an existing Ethernet interface. The place to create the new NetworkService is under "NetworkServices", and if your Mac has an Ethernet device the NetworkService profile will also be under this property entry. The Ethernet entry can be copied pretty much verbatim, the only fields you would actually be changing are:

- UUID
- UserDefinedName
- IPv4 configuration and set the interface to your tun or tap device (i.e. tun0 or tap0).
- DNS server if needed.

Then you would also manipulate the particular Location you want this NetworkService for (remember Mac OS X can configure all network interfaces dependent on your "Location"). The default location UUID can be obtained in the root of the PropertyList as the key "CurrentSet". After figuring out which location (or set) you want, expand the Set property, and add entries under Global/IPv4/ServiceOrder with the UUID of the new NetworkService. Also under the Set property you need to expand the Service property and add the UUID here as a dictionary with one String entry with key __LINK__ and value as the UUID (use the other interfaces as an example).

After you have modified your `preferences.plist` file, just reboot, and the NetworkService will be available under SystemPreferences->Network. Note that we have mimicked an Ethernet device so Mac OS X layer of networking will note that "a cable is unplugged" and will not let you activate the interface through the GUI. However, since the underlying device is a tun/tap device and it has an IP address, the interface will become active and the proper routing will be added at the BSD level.

**As a reference this is used to do special routing magic.**

In case you got this far and are having trouble, you have to create the tun/tap device by opening one of the devices under /dev/. You can use any program to do this, but I'm a fan of good-old-fashioned C myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   int fd = open("/dev/tun0", O_RDONLY);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
      printf("Failed to open tun/tap device. Are you root? Are the drivers installed?\n");
      return -1;
   }
   while (1)
   {
      sleep(100000);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this solution allow you to turn on "Internet Sharing" to bridge the tap interface to the ethernet or airport interface?

Comment: I've tested it and yes, it does. I was able to share my OpenVPN tun0 device (from my Ethernet connection) over my WiFi using this method.

Comment: Note: I tried this to a vmnet (VMware virtual network adapter) and I can't get it active with an IP. (For uses with tun/tap devices as discussed this solution really works)

Comment: Is there a way around the "a cable is unplugged" issue?  I followed the instructions and they work great, however with the "cable unplugged" OS X believes that the host is offline and trying navigate to any site in my browser tells me there is no internet connection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm testing your way in MacOS 12 Monterey, but open("/dev/tun0") will always return false. I think the tuntap (used `brew install --cask tuntap` to install) gets wrong somewhere. Is there a way to use tuntap in  MacOS 12?

Answer (score 14):

In regards to `@bmasterswizzle`'s [BRILLIANT answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375307/547214) - more specifically - to `@DanRamos`' question about how to force the new interface's link-state to "up".. I use this script, of whose origin I cannot recall, but which works fabulously (in coordination with [@bmasterswizzles "Mona Lisa" of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375307/547214))...

```
#!/bin/zsh

[[ "$UID" -ne "0" ]] && echo "You must be root. Goodbye..." && exit 1
echo "starting"
exec 4<>/dev/tap0
ifconfig tap0 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.255
ifconfig tap0 up
ping -c1 10.10.10.1
echo "ending"
export PS1="tap interface>"
dd of=/dev/null <&4 & # continuously reads from buffer and dumps to null
```

I am NOT quite sure I understand the alteration to the prompt at the end, or...

> `dd of=/dev/null <&4 & # continuously reads from buffer and dumps to null`

but WHATEVER. it works.  link light: *green*✅.  **loves it**.

[image]

Comment: How can you destroy the tap adapter (via script)?

Comment: If you want to make a Python implementation, you might want to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139727/1097104 as a basis.

Comment: It gives me the following error: line 5: /dev/tap0: Operation not permitted

Comment: Still working in `MacOS 12 Monterey`? I tested and failed.

Comment: You need Tunnelblick, and the following informations to use the TAP device driver from Tunnelblick: https://groups.google.com/g/tunnelblick-discuss/c/v5wnQCRZ8HY/m/Q8nhFBx1BgAJ

After installing Tunnelblick, you can load a tap kext with the following command in Terminal (or a script):

```
/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpnstart loadKexts 2
```

Answer (score 10):

A few others seemed to hint at this, but the following demonstrates using ifconfig to create a vlan and test DNS on the virtual interface (using [minidns](https://code.google.com/p/minidns/)) on OS X 10.9.5:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.9.5
$ sudo ifconfig vlan169 create && echo vlan169 created
vlan169 created
$ sudo ifconfig vlan169 inet 169.254.169.254 netmask 255.255.255.255 && echo vlan169 configured
vlan169 configured
$ sudo ./minidns.py 169.254.169.254 &
[1] 35125
$ miniDNS :: * 60 IN A 169.254.169.254


$ dig @169.254.169.254 +short test.host
Request: test.host. -> 169.254.169.254
Request: test.host. -> 169.254.169.254
169.254.169.254
$ sudo kill 35125
$ 
[1]+  Exit 143                sudo ./minidns.py 169.254.169.254
$ sudo ifconfig vlan169 destroy && echo vlan169 destroyed
vlan169 destroyed
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to use TUN/TAP device.
http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: User yar made a similar suggestion through a blog post. I've looked at it, but I didn't test it out, because of lack of time and I don't have the need anymore. Nevertheless thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on a dev environment and want access some service already running on localhost/host machine. in docker for mac you have another option.use docker.for.mac.localhost instead of localhost in docker container.
docker.for.mac.host.internal should be used instead of docker.for.mac.localhost from Docker Community Edition 17.12.0-ce-mac46 2018-01-09.
this allows you to connect to service running on your on mac from within a docker container.please refer below links

[understanding the docker.for.mac.localhost behavior](https://forums.docker.com/t/understanding-the-docker-for-mac-localhost-behavior/41921)

[release notes](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac46-2018-01-09)

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> "but it will not act as a real fully functional interface (if the original interface is inactive, then the derived one is also inactive"

?

I can make a new interface, base it on an already existing one, then disable the existing one and the new one still works. Making a second interface does however not create a real interface (when you check with ifconfig), it will just assign a second IP to the already existing one (however, this one can be DHCP while the first one is hard coded for example).

So did I understand you right, that you want to create an interface, not bound to any real interface? How would this interface then be used? E.g. if you disconnect all WLAN and pull all network cables, where would this interface send traffic to, if you send traffic to it? Maybe your question is a bit unclear, it might help a lot if rephrase it, so it's clear what you are actually trying to do with this "virtual interface" once you have it.

As you mentioned "alias IP" in your question, this would mean an alias interface. But an alias interface is always bound to a real interface. The difference is in Linux such an interface really **IS** an interface (e.g. an alias interface for eth0 could be eth1), while on Mac, no *real* interface is created, instead a virtual interface is created, that can configured and used independently, but it is still the same interface physically and thus no new named interface is generated (you just have two interfaces, that are both in fact en0, but both can be enabled/disabled and configured independently).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Network Preferences.

At the bottom of the list of network adapters, click the **+** icons

Select the existing interface that you want to arp (say Ethernet 1), and give the Service Name that you want for the new port (say Ethernet 1.1)  then press create.

Now you have the new virtual interface in the gui and can manage IP addresses etc it in the normal way.

ifconfig -a will confirm that you have multiple IPs on the interface,  and these will still be there when you reboot.

Its a Mac.  Don't fight it, do it the easy way.

Comment: As noted in the original question, this doesn't achieve the desired effect of a virtual interface isolated from a physical interface. The command you described simply aliases the same physical interface with a second IP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i have resorted to running PFSense, a BSD based router/firewall to achieve this goal….

why?  because OS X Server gets so FREAKY without a Static IP…

so after wrestling with it for DAYS to make NAT and DHCP and firewall and …

I'm trying this is parallels…

will let ya know how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial, it's for FreeBSD but also applies to OS X. http://people.freebsd.org/~arved/vlan/vlan_en.html

Answer (score -1):

ifconfig interfacename create will create a virtual interface,

Comment: Could you provide an example for that? If I try that, it does not work and has never worked as far as I know.

Comment: ifconfig vlan0 create as documented in the ifconfig man page

"create  Create the specified network pseudo-device.  If the interface is given without a unit number, try to create a new device with an arbitrary unit number."

Comment: It will not work as the vlan0 above cannot be made active (status) and so it will not receive any packets...

Comment: Well your question related a virtual interface, without any indication about what you wanted to do with it, which is specifically what I answered. This feature is for vlans, you can do something like

ifconfig vlan0 vlan sometag vlandev en0
ipconfig set vlan0 DHCP

If a vlan is your goal.

Comment: @HansDoggen do you know why the vlan interface cannot be made active?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20160301104014/http://gerrydevstory.com/2012/08/20/how-to-create-virtual-network-interface-on-mac-os-x/

Basically you select a network adapter in the Networks pane of system preferences, then click the gear to "Duplicate Service". After the service is duplicated, you manually assign an IP in one of the private address ranges. Then ping it to make sure ;)

Comment: The original post is asking help for create one **NEW** **virtual** networking interface, not asking for adding new IP address for an **existing** networking interface.

Comment: I agree that the question clearly specifies a virtual interface, and my answer and the link I provided don't delineate between a virtual interface and a physical interface. However the question doesn't really ask for any of this in particular. It asks for "something similar" to making a Virtual Network Device in Windows.