# Software network interface tunnel to localhost on OSX

Tags: macos, localhost, tunnel, ifconfig

I want to verify that my network monitoring program on Mac can handle network interfaces that come and go. For example, the user could attach a Wifi adapter via Thunderbolt, and my program must notice that.

So, I set up Python server to run in in *localhost:8000*. Running `wget http://localhost:8000` on the command line gives me a valid response from the Python server. Direct communication with the localhost succeeds. So far so good.

Next, I wrote a Python script, setting up a software network interface, tunneling traffic from 10.0.2.1 to localhost. However, the tunnel is obviously not correctly set up because the script hangs on the `wget` part:

```
import os
try:
    os.system("ifconfig gif6 create")
    os.system("ifconfig gif6 inet 10.0.2.1 127.0.0.1 up")
    os.system("wget http://10.0.2.1:8000")
finally:
    os.system("ifconfig gif6 destroy")
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to set up the 10.0.2.1 <-> 127.0.0.1 tunnel? There is probably something wrong in the [ifconfig](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html) commands but I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: I managed to work around the issue with TUN/TAP driver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139727/1097104