# Emulating a virtual host for UDP communication

Tags: udp, virtualization

First of all this question is not about virtual host in Apache.

I have a network with the following address: 1.1.1.0

I have several host on this network: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3 and 1.1.1.4

The first host send a broadcast UDP paquet answer and expect other host to answer him.

Is it possible for my dev machine (1.1.1.4) to emulate the following virtual host : 1.1.1.5, 1.1.1.6, etc. ?

I'm using [QUdpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QUdpSocket.html) from Qt 5.2.1 on MacOS 10.9 but I am open to any other tech that would help me do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on you OS.

On linux, you can create multiple virtual network devices, and bind each of those devices to a different network address.  The virtual network devices have the name of a real device with a `:xxx` numeric suffix.  For example, if your primary network device is `eth0`, you can run the command

```
ifconfig eth0:1 1.1.1.5
```

to create the virtual device `eth0:1` and bind it to the address 1.1.1.5.  This is only temporary (it will go away when you reboot); if you want it to come back when you reboot, you can edit the `/etc/network/interfaces file to look something like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.1.1.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 1.1.1.1

auto eth0:1
    address 1.1.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

the lack of a `gateway` in the `eth0:1` part means that it won't use this interface for routing, so it just exists for receiving packets and explicit binding to an ip address.

Comment: I will try with that and tell you how it works! I'm thinking about script it with ruby!

Comment: It doesn't work on MacOS but I found the equivalent here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/624660/118125

Answer (score 1):

Install VirtualBox ([here](https://www.virtualbox.org)) and make a tiny disk image big enough for a small Linux distro. Run several copies, each one at a different IP address and run a tiny `netcat` script in each one that listens and sends replies.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   command=$(nc -ul 1234)
   process $command and reply
done
```

Or, read [this](http://gerrydevstory.com/2012/08/20/how-to-create-virtual-network-interface-on-mac-os-x/) and go with Chris's idea which is lighter weight on resources!