# How to force MacOS to send network packets to local proxy even when Wi-Fi is not connected

Tags: macos, networking

MacOS version: Mojave

I have a program listening on a local port(2080). I would like to forward all network requests to this program.

In order to accomplish this, I have configured the Wi-Fi network service to use a socks5 proxy as well as dns server pointing to local host.

This works as long as the Wi-Fi network service is connected to any network, regardless wether that network is connected to the internet. (For instance, a chromecast).

Is there a way to force the packages to the program without having to connect to a network?

Previous attempts include creating a network service attached to the lookback device, lo0, with the proxy and dns settings as before (couldn't get any packets to be routed through the program, network panel says not connected) And installing tun/tap discussed in this question.([Virtual network interface in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87442/virtual-network-interface-in-mac-os-x/6375307#6375307)).
The device will show up in ifconfig, but not in network services after editing the SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

Any guidance is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. The Tun/Tap will work, just need to configure the virtual network service with correct DNS and proxy settings.